# Inverse of strictly diagonally dominant matrix with smaller off-diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a matrix $A$ with all positive entries and the diagonal entries are very large than off-diagonal entries. Moreover, the off-diagonal entries are all less than 1. How to analytically prove that the inverse of $A$ will always have negative off-diagonal entries?
I tried in Matlab, but so far, I have not got any contradictions. I don't know how to proceed further. Any hint will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true.  Consider, for example,
$$ A = \pmatrix{1 & s & t\cr 0 & 1 & s\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr},\ A^{-1} = \pmatrix{1 & -s & s^2-t\cr 0 & 1 & -s\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr}$$
where $(A^{-1})_{13} = s^2-t$ could have either sign.
I realize that the bottom left entries of $A$ are $0$ rather than strictly positive,
but if you take an example where $s^2-t > 0$ and change those $0$'s to a sufficiently small number $\epsilon > 0$, $(A^{-1})_{13}$ will still be positive.

Comment: Can I take please take liberty to ask you here itself: what if the diagonal entries are greater than 1. I am given question that diagonal entries are very large. So, probably the inverse off-diagonal entries are negative to compensate for that.

Comment: Everything scales: $(c A)^{-1} = c^{-1} A^{-1}$.